# Combine category codes from two different DataFrames and then apply it as a column to each DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am playing with the famous Titanic dataset.

I have the `train.csv` and `test.csv` loaded into an array of size two called `combined`. and concatenated the `Ticket` column of each like this:

`all_tickets = combined[0]['Ticket'].append(combined[1]['Ticket'])`

Now, my goal is to apply the same categorical codes to each DataFrame. However, when I tried this for the first one:

`combined[0]['TicketCode'] = all_tickets.astype('category').cat.codes`

It complained: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

It makes sense since both sets are from different sizes. How can I achieve my goal in this situation? Grouping the Tickets with a range enumerator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I just built a `dictionary` and applied to both `DataFrames`:

```
ticket_codes = {}
i = 0
grouped_series = combined[0]['Ticket'].append(combined[1]['Ticket'])
for g, _ in grouped_series.groupby(grouped_series):
    ticket_codes[g] = i
    i = i + 1

for x in positions:
    combined[x]['TicketCode'] = combined[x]['Ticket'].apply(lambda y: ticket_codes[y])
```